# Does 1st Corinthians chapter 15 say that we will have a permanent physical life?

Tags: nature-of-god, exegesis, eternal-life

All Scriptures ar quoted from the King James translation.

In Chapter 15 of first Corinthians Paul talks about in the resurrection of Jesus, which was a resurrection of Jesus physical body. Other versus would lead one to believe that all people will be resurrected to a physical body which is the same as the one in which they abide while on the Earth.

In other Scriptures that seems to be conflicting with what they say. Here are some of the Scriptures which Paul wrote in chapter 15 which tend to cause one to believe he is proposing a physical life of a permanent nature; and that he talks about the resurrection of others:

> 1st Corinthians 15:4  And that he was buried, and that he rose again the third day according to the scriptures:

I agree with that statement the wholeheartedly and I believe that Jesus did return in the same physical body which he died. But Jesus was not an ordinary man. And I believe that the reason he came in that same physical body is because of the following Scripture:

> Psalm 16:10  For thou wilt not leave my soul in hell; neither wilt thou suffer thine Holy One to see corruption.

Later on in the chapter. Paul makes these statements:

> 1st Corinthians 15:12 and 13
>
> Now if Christ be preached that he rose from the dead, how say some among you that there is no resurrection of the dead? But if there be no resurrection of the dead, then is Christ not risen:

While I agree with Paul that there will be other resurrections two of which are mentioned in the revelation:

> Rev 20:5  But the rest of the dead lived not again until the thousand years were finished. This is the first resurrection.
>
> Rev 20:13  And the sea gave up the dead which were in it; and death and hell delivered up the dead which were in them: and they were judged every man according to their works.

Probably the best-known news of the resurrections is what is called the rapture.

1st Thessalonians 4:15 through 17

> For this we say unto you by the word of the Lord, that we which are alive and remain unto the coming of the Lord shall not prevent them which are asleep. For the Lord himself shall descend from heaven with a shout, with the voice of the archangel, and with the trump of God: and the dead in Christ shall rise first: Then we which are alive and remain shall be caught up together with them in the clouds, to meet the Lord in the air: and so shall we ever be with the Lord.

But there is a vast difference between the body of Jesus and the bodies of we mortal men:

> Genesis 3:19  In the sweat of thy face shalt thou eat bread, till thou return unto the ground; for out of it wast thou taken: for dust thou art, and unto dust shalt thou return.

Jesus the man was very special. For one thing he had:

John 10:17 and 18

> Therefore doth my Father love me, because I lay down my life, that I might take it again. No man taketh it from me, but I lay it down of myself. I have power to lay it down, and I have power to take it again. This commandment have I received of my Father.

As I read these Scriptures I am able to extract three different things from them.

```
1. God the father gave Jesus a command, that he should come to the Earth and of his
own volition die and take up his life again.

2. Jesus was not killed. He willingly sacrificed his earthly life on the cross.

3. Jesus himself, gave his human body life again.
```

This seems much more plausible, when we take into consideration in John 1:1 through 4:

> In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God. The same was in the beginning with God. All things were made by him; and without him was not any thing made that was made. In him was life; and the life was the light of men.

If I read that passage correctly; it was Jesus who breathed the breath of life into Adam:

> Genesis 2:7  And the LORD God formed man of the dust of the ground, and breathed into his nostrils the breath of life; and man became a living soul.

If I read and the Scriptures which I quoted correctly, our physical bodies must return to dust. I do believe that after the resurrection we will have a new body but it will be a resurrection body and not the same physical body which we now have.

> 1st John 3:2  Beloved, now are we the sons of God, and it doth not yet appear what we shall be: but we know that, when he shall appear, we shall be like him; for we shall see him as he is.

I do not believe that a physical body is immortal. I only believe that the soul is immortal; but that we will be given a new resurrection body which will be nothing like the physical body we now have. After all it will have to last for eternity, and I for one would not like to spend eternity in this bald headed, pot bellied, flat footed, and worn out body I am currently inhabiting.  I guess though that it would really be my just reward.

I hope I have not misread these Scriptures, but if I have let me know so I can work on getting used to having this same body for eternity.

P.S. maybe there won't be any mirrors in Heaven. A guy can hope can't he!

Comment: So I'm revisiting this question again and I'm not really sure what you're saying. When you say we'll receive a 'resurrection body', is that a physical body?

Comment: @curiousdannii Sorry for not answering sooner I was not aware of your question, for some reason. I do not know the answer to your question, as John said in 1st John 3:2  Beloved, now are we the sons of God, and it doth not yet appear what we shall be: but we know that, when he shall appear, we shall be like him; for we shall see him as he is.

Comment: So are you really just asking, is the final state of heaven, after life, after resurrection, after rapture, after millennium, and whatever you think of those, A physical eternal new heaven and new earth?

Comment: The real issue seems to be here "I do believe that after the resurrection we will have a new body but it will be a resurrection body and not the same physical body which we now have." The question seems to be: Is the body in the resurrection the same as we have now (with all its weaknesses like baldness or whatever), or a new/changed one (without those weaknesses). And not whether we will have a physical body at all. OP is currently uncomfortable with his body and wants to know whether he will be eternally uncomfortable.

Comment: @kutschkem To me the question is not if we will have the same body; but instead is that a physical body at all? If we are to be like him my Bible tells me that God is a Spirit and must be worshipped in Spirit. If we are to continuously worship God then we must be a Spirit, especially since Heaven is a Spiritual Kingdom. Will we be in Heaven or the new Heaven and Earth in the Revelation chapter 21?

Comment: @BYE with this question you go into territory that is answered differently by different denominations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paul in his first epistle to the Corinthians reminds them Corinthians of the gospel he taught them:

1 Corinthians 15:1-8 NKJV

> Moreover, brethren, I declare to you the gospel which I preached to you, which also you received and in which you stand, 2  by which also you are saved, if you hold fast that word which I preached to you—unless you believed in vain. 3  For I delivered to you first of all that which I also received: that Christ died for our sins according to the Scriptures, 4  and that He was buried, and that He rose again the third day according to the Scriptures, 5  and that He was seen by Cephas, then by the twelve. 6  After that He was seen by over five hundred brethren at once, of whom the greater part remain to the present, but some have fallen asleep. 7  After that He was seen by James, then by all the apostles. 8  Then last of all He was seen by me also, as by one born out of due time.

By equating the earlier appearances of the risen Jesus with the appearance to himself, Paul appears to suggest that he believed all the post-crucifixion appearances to be spiritual rather than physical.  Paul portrays the resurrection of Jesus as the 'type' for the general resurrection to come.

John Dominic Crossan says in *The Birth of Christianity*, page xix,

> that it never occurs to Paul that Jesus' resurrection might be a special or unique privilege given to him because he is Messiah, Lord, and Son of God. Resurrection of the dead was a Jewish, apocalyptic notion that did not make sense to Greeks, and the Corinthians had gone so far as to say,
>
> 1Co 15:12  Now if Christ is preached that He has been raised from the dead, how do some among you say that there is no resurrection of the dead?
>
> Paul asks how some Corinthians can say there is no resurrection of the dead if Christ is preached as raised from the dead, because if there is no resurrection of the dead, then neither has Christ been raised, in which case their faith is for nothing. He calls them fools for believing that the resurrected will come back in their earthly bodies. He says there are earthly bodies, which are corruptible, and heavenly bodies, which are not (1st Corinthians 15:40).
>
> To Greeks, the notion of a resurrected body was distasteful but Paul did not want to talk about resurrection of invisible souls.

Burton L. Mack, in hos book *Who Wrote the New Testament*, pages 132 & 3:

> says he therefore proposed what surely must be the most preposterous conceptual equation of all his attempts to bridge the intellectual traditions of Jewish and Greek cultures - the notion of a “spiritual body”.  He argues that:
>
> - There are many kinds of bodies among animals and human beings, and the “bodies of plants are different from the ‘bodies’ of the seeds from which they come.
> - There are earthly bodies and “heavenly bodies” (with reference to sun, moon, and stars:  15:40-41).
> - The first man, Adam, had a “physical body”; the “man from heaven” (Christ) had a “spiritual body”.
> - The resurrection of Christ was the first fruits of the general resurrection of Christians which would take place at the eschaton.
> - At the general resurrection, the bodies of the dead would be changed into imperishable bodies just like the heavenly body of Christ (15:52-54).

This “spiritual body” is not a physical body like our natural bodies, but it is more than just an invisible soul. In verse 51, Paul resolves his difficulty by calling it a mystery.

more information about the two books cited above can be found at these websites.
http://www.johndominiccrossan.com/The%20Birth%20of%20Christianity.htm
and.
http://www.jesuspuzzle.humanists.net/review1.htm

Comment: I know this will get some negative reviews, so I point out: i) Crossan was president of the Chicago Society of Biblical Research in 1978–1979, and  president of the Society of Biblical Literature in 2012, described as ”Generally acknowledged as the premier historical Jesus scholar in the world"; ii) Mack was Professor of early Christianity at the School of Theology at Claremont and Associate scholar at the Institute for Antiquity and Christianity at Claremont

Comment: If this is a quote you need to say so and give credit to the Author. I was recently up braded for a similar omission. I have learned since that there are specific rules for how to publish on this site. most are easily accessible just above the narrative section. Also Biblical quotations need be in specific form. As written this appears to be plagiarism.

Comment: @Bye Thank you kindly for the advice. You will notice that I did indeed credit Crossan and Mack for the material I used from their books. The concluding paragraph is my own words, synthesised from the epistle and the two books I had previously cited. Thanks again.

Comment: Would you mind if I edit your answer to show how it should be formatted for the site?

Comment: Please go ahead. I want to learn to be a better contributor to the site. As long as the final result retains my original sense. I find the sister site, BH easier because the rules are limited to hermenautics.

Comment: If you do not agree with my edit you can back it off by clicking on my edit and on the popup page back it off. you might like to do that and rewrite it yourself as I may have misquoted something. You also have the option of editing my edit if you so desire. I did make one glaring mistake which should be corrected All Scripture came from the new King James version and so (NKJV) should be inserted after the verse numbers.

Comment: @Bye Thx for your assistance. I especially like the references to the books, if you like to show that these are real books I was quoting. Sorry for using hard-copy, but I nearly always assume that if a scholar is willing to go into print, without the option of ever changing it, then this is more reliable than many internet sites (esp Wikipedia). I had difficulty trying to edit yours, but you may have noticed that I said, "says that." This is indirect citation, which I prefer for reasons of copyright (words are copyright, ideas not so), so not in yellow. As a non-US, I also hate "1 through 8".

Comment: I don't know about your first point. Luke/Acts seem pretty clear about a bodily resurrection. If Paul likens his experience to theirs maybe he's saying he saw Jesus bodily too.

Comment: @curiousdannii Paul did not write Luke/Acts, so I was working from his own personal account. Many scholars have noted instances where Paul's accounts differ from Acts. The trend now is for critical scholars not to regard Acts as historical unless backed up by other sources. In fact, some believe Acts' Damascus vision was inspired by the Bacchae.

Comment: It's an interesting idea. By far the most plausible I've heard for a non bodily resurrection. But it's not obvious that he must have seen a non bodily appearance.

Answer (score 2):

We know from Scripture that Jesus possessed a physical body like ours. He could sweat (Luke 22:44), grow weary (John 4:6), and even be endure physical pain (resurrection story). Upon being resurrected we see Jesus possess a new body. This new body can eat physical food (Luke 24:42-43), hide his appearance (John 20:14, 21:4), walk through walls (John 20:19, 26), and it even retains wounds which no longer affect the health of the body (John 20:20, 27). The idea that is represented in this is that God embraces and redeems His creation. One of the ways we see Him embracing us is through the incarnation of Jesus. An important thing to note is that Jesus never separated Himself from His humanity. What we see in Jesus resurrected body is how God redeems his creation. In 2 Corinthians 5:17 and Philippians 3:20-21 Paul tells us that we will be made into a new creation through some type of bodily transformation. In order to get this new body we must first die in the one we have (1 Corinthians 15:35-38). Just like Jesus says about the grain of wheat in John 12:24:

> “Truly, truly, I say to you, unless a grain of wheat falls into the earth and dies, it remains alone; but if it dies, it bears much fruit.” (NASB)

This parallels the idea that Paul teaches a few verses down in 1 Corinthians 15:42-44:

> “42 So also is the resurrection of the dead. It is sown a perishable body, it is raised an imperishable body; 
>   43 it is sown in dishonor, it is raised in glory; it is sown in weakness, it is raised in power; 
>   44 it is sown a natural body, it is raised a spiritual body. If there is a natural body, there is also a spiritual body.” (NASB)

Our new bodies will be a transformation of our physical bodies. They will emerge from our current ones in a renewed state. Romans 8:11:

> “But if the Spirit of Him who raised Jesus from the dead dwells in you, He who raised Christ Jesus from the dead will also give life to your mortal bodies through His Spirit who dwells in you.” (NASB)

In Matthew 10:28 Jesus alludes to this idea that there will be a bodily form present in the next life. If you do find your resurrected body is still an exact copy of your current physical one, perhaps we can hope that John 20:14 and John 21:4 are hinting that we have some control over how we look (joking of course). But in all seriousness, Scripture does demonstrate that our resurrected bodies will come from the death of our physical ones.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the C.SE! Although your answer sounds plausible, it'd be better if you could state the denomination from which you speak. If your denomination has an official stance on this subject, then cite that. If your answer is influenced in any particular way to your school of thought, it is highly recommended that you cite that too. We don't do independent research here; we just report the established facts.

Answer (score 1):

Not so much. It tells me we may need a body as a token to swap for a new body.

The earthly body is asleep, resurrected, then swapped for a new heavenly body while waiting for the final judgement (2 Cor 5:1-10).

For the New Heaven, the heavenly body from (2 Cor 5) has to be impure or be purified (Revelation 21:27).

(This might be a partial answer)